# Append/join (bit shift) one binary value before another in Java

Tags: java, binary, append

I want be able to 'insert/append' one binary after another. They are int variables at the moment.

```
int i = 1;
int j = 4;
```

I want to bit shift left by 3 for `i` then add the values together.

For example,

```
i binary: 1 (1)
j binary: 100 (4)

Result: 1100 (12)
```

Comment: is 100 and 1 (or) 4 and 1 are variables?

Comment: @Dilip No, I think that's console output.

Comment: @ritch *where* do you want to put those values? Are you talking about bit operations?

Comment: @MaxLeske I just wanted to understand sample input and sample output. That is why am asking.

Comment: So I have two int's 1 and 4.

Comment: Ok, I get it. What you want is basically a `bit shift left by 3` + `bit or`, right?

Comment: Then you should update your question with that information :)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int appendBinary(int i, int j)
{
    String iStr = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    String jStr = Integer.toBinaryString(j);
    String binary = iStr + jStr;
    return Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
}
```

This method simply converts i and j to binary, then subs i before j, and converts the result to an int. Hope this helps!